# How exactly does Auhtorization in web applications work?

Tags: security, web

First, i know that there are to components of handling user access to restricted pages in web appliations.

Authentification is about identifying a user.

Authorization: is about determining what parts of the application an authenticated user has access to

I belive this is made with session id.

But does the client have to send the session id with every request he makes? If not how can he be authentified? Or is a cookie used for this?

Comment: If using sessions , the SessionID would need to be sent with every request . This can be included as a parameter in the request URL , or as a POSTed parameter , or saved in a Cookie whose value would be sent with every request .

Comment: are there other ways than using sessions?

Answer (score 1):

Sessions exist on the server. They are sometimes (usually) identified by a cookie.

The session can contain a multitude of information that is relevant to the session. E.g. shopping basket.

Server gets the cookie. Looks up the session. Has it timed out? Is it from the same IP address? From the same browser perhaps? Then use the stored information for the generation of the web page

Comment: PS: Passwords are a one way street - Your server should never give them out. In fact the server should not know them! They should be encrypted.

Comment: They should not even be encrypted, but hashed - hasing is also a one way street. You can hash a password, but you cannot easily "un hash" it.

Answer (score 0):

Session still among pages, but it would be destroyed when you close your browser
Cookies still sometime when the time expires

Comment: This is untrue - Sessions exist on the server

Comment: @EdHeal I know, but here I mean on the client , sessions let you browse between pages

Comment: They are not destroyed when you close your browser